# SSAS Calculated fields

Tags: ssas

I have a few calculated fields in my Cube.  I want to set it up when the users are querying the data within Excel if they add one of the calculated fields to the values, if they hover over the value it gives the definition of how the calculation was created.  Is this possible?

Ex.  AHT = Tot_wrk_tm/vol

Comment: What do you mean by "calculated fields"? Calculated measures? Calculated members of another hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, I meant Calculated Measures.  They are of the same hierarchy, I'm just tryign to be able to display the description in Excel when a user is viewing the summary data.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the client tool that you have: If you have your own client tool, and just need to access the definition of measures, you can execute the following SQL the same way that you execute MDX select statements (but be aware the result is tabular, not a cellset):

```
select [MEASURE_NAME], [EXPRESSION]
  from $system.mdschema_measures
 where [CUBE_NAME] = '<your cube name>'
```

This will return all measures, and calculated measures have their expression in the `EXPRESSION` column. This works from version 2008.

If your users use a standard tool where you have no influence on the display, then you will need an attribute which displays the calculation, as then this can be shown with normal cube access. To implement this, create a named query in your data source view which generates a single column and a single row. I will assume the named query as well as the dimension built from it are named "Def", and the column and the attribute built furtehr down from it are called "definition". Its value should be what you want to display for non-calculated measures, e. g. an empty string. If you use SQL Server as your relational source, the query definition could be something like

```
select '' as definition
```

There is no need to relate this to any table. Create a new dimension from this, and make `definition` its only attribute. Set its `IsAggregatable` property to false. Add this dimension to the cube (in Cube editor, tab "Cube Structure", in the bottom left, right click on your cube and select "Add Cube Dimension"). There is no need to set any relationship on the "Dimension Usage" tab.

Deploy the solution, and then change the "Default Member" property of the `Definition` attribute to use the single member. This is necessary as you did set the `IsAggregatable` property to false.

Finally, in the calculation script of the cube add the following:

```
SCOPE([Measures].[AHT]);
   [Def].[Definition].[] = 'Tot_wrk_tm/vol';
END SCOPE;
```

Use the unique name of the member to the left of the equals; this can be dragged from the list of elements of the cube to the script in Cube Editor/Calculations tab. And repeat these three lines for all calculated measures that you want to document.

Your users can then drag this attribute to their report wherever it makes sense, and it would display the text you configured. Of course, you must make sure that for each change of the definition of any calculated measure, the code for the definition attribute must be adapted. There is no auto-generation.